# Data Verify based on Dropdownlist Selection in ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, web

I have a Selection List in my View and I am trying to call it in my Controller. I have 2 requirements to satisfy.

1 - If the user selects SSN, then the TaxID input should be equal to SSN in my Table.

2 - If the user selects FEIN, then the TaxID input should be equal to FEIN in my Table.

I am not sure how to write the condition where the system would check as per the above requirements.

I have the controller Code where the system can check only one condition.

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CorporationRegistrationPg1", "Corporation", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<body>
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TAxIDType, Model.TAxIDType)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TaxID, new { @class = "feintextbox", maxlength = 9, @placeholder = "xxxxxxxxx" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.TaxID)

@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EmailID, new { @class = "emailid" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EmailID)
</body>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult CorporationRegistrationPg1(Testing CorporationRegistration, string EmailID, int TaxID, string TAxIDType)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (SUPRTestingDBEntities2 db = new SUPRTestingDBEntities2())
                {
                    if (TAxIDType == "SSN")
                    {
                        var obj = db.SUPRTesting.Where(a => a.EmailID.Equals(CorporationRegistration.EmailID) && a.TaxID.Equals(CorporationRegistration.SSN)).FirstOrDefault();

                        if (obj != null)
                        {
                            if (obj.Active == 0 && obj.Submit == 0)
                            {
                                Session["LoginID"] = obj.LoginID.ToString();
                                Session["EmailAddress"] = obj.EmailID.ToString();
                                return RedirectToAction("CorporationRegistrationPg2");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return View();
                            }
                        }
                        else if (obj == null)
                        {
                            return View();
                        }
                    }
                    else if (TAxIDType=="FEIN")
                    {
                        var obj = db.SUPRTesting.Where(a => a.EmailID.Equals(CorporationRegistration.EmailID) && a.TaxID.Equals(CorporationRegistration.FEIN)).FirstOrDefault();

                        if (obj != null)
                        {
                            if (obj.Active == 0 && obj.Submit == 0)
                            {
                                Session["LoginID"] = obj.LoginID.ToString();
                                Session["EmailAddress"] = obj.EmailID.ToString();
                                return RedirectToAction("CorporationRegistrationPg2");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return View();
                            }
                        }
                        else if (obj == null)
                        {
                            return View();
                        }
                    }}
            }return View();
        }
```

In the Controller, I am trying to call the TaxIDType, and I am able to pass the value. But, the new problems are I am unable to check if the TaxID is equal to SSN/FEIN as the system always returns SSN/FEIN as 0 even though I have data in there and system is returning to the same page.

The second problem is when the the system returns to the same page, the dropdown is throwing an error:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' 
System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.Model.get returned null.

Can Someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

How about you remove the textbox for TaxID and resolve based on the option selected in the dropdown:

Comment: Hey Duncan, I made few changes to the problem. I was able to fix the dropdown issue, somewhat. I have two new issues.

Comment: You need to repopulate the Model.TAxIDType on the post action,,, 

in your case you are returning a view with no model >> return View();

Comment: Got it, thank you. I was able to fix this issue. I still haven't resolved the 1st problem.